# html/jquery - form doesnt submit when its across multiple table td's

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm appending row dynamically into my html table which is containing form with id "update", on submit I want to send values from multiple select with id #myselect and textarea with id "#note".
I'm also using bootstrap to style my document elements.

But there is problem when both of my elements are in separate table cells, submit button is appearing outside of form so it wont trigger submit action.

"#deleteit" form working fine, but "#update" does nothing on submit

```js
$('#mytable > tbody').append("<tr><td>1</td><td>name</td><td><form id='update'><select multiple class='form-control' id='myselect' name='myselects'><option>test1</option><option>test2</option></select></td><td><textarea class='form-control' id='note' name='notes' rows='3'></textarea></td><td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>update</button></form></td><td><form id='deleteit' method='post'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>delete</button></form></td></tr>");

$(document).on('submit', '#update', function(e) {
  alert("update form submitted")
  return false
});

$(document).on('submit', '#deleteit', function(e) {
  alert("delete form submitted")
  return false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Update button is inside the form.. </button></form>

Comment: So you think. See the rendered code - your HTML is invalid: `<tr><td>1</td><td>name</td><td><form id="update"><select multiple="" class="form-control" id="myselect" name="myselects"><option>test1</option><option>test2</option></select></form></td><td><textarea class="form-control" id="note" name="notes" rows="3"></textarea></td><td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">update</button></td><td><form id="deleteit" method="post"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">delete</button></form></td></tr>`

Comment: The question is - why it's rendering "update" button outside of form, or why </form> appearing in DOM earlier than it should

Comment: You cannot append a form across table cells. It will close the form where it feels it is valid to do so. Instead wrap the form around the row or the table and have one submit and one button

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid.

Replace it by that :

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>
    <form id='update'>
      <select multiple class='form-control' id='myselect' name='myselects'>
        <option>test1</option>
        <option>test2</option>
      </select> 
      <textarea class='form-control' id='note' name='notes' rows='3'></textarea> 
      <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>update</button> 
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form id='deleteit' method='post'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>delete</button></form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And your update event will be triggered.

Working example :

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('#mytable > tbody').append("<tr><td>1</td><td>name</td><td> <form id='update'> <select multiple class='form-control' id='myselect' name='myselects'> <option>test1</option> <option>test2</option> </select> <textarea class='form-control' id='note' name='notes' rows='3'></textarea> <button type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>update</button> </form> </td><td> <form id='deleteit' method='post'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>delete</button></form> </td></tr>");

  $(document).on('submit', '#update', function(e) {
    alert("update form submitted");
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('submit', '#deleteit', function(e) {
    alert("delete form submitted");
    return false;
  });
</script>
```